# stream is undefined when using navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc

I am using webrtc and trying to show the video after obtaining permission of `getUserMedia()`

here is what I am trying to do

```js
var mediaConstraints = { audio: true, video: true };

const stream = await navigator.getUserMedia
        (mediaConstraints, function() {
            console.log("obtained successfully");

    }, function() {
        console.error("access was denied OR hardware issue");
        });
```

however stream is `undefied`, it should have a value of any kind

Comment: Which _mediaConstraints_ do you pass?

Comment: @IgorKhvostenkov I have edited the question and added the missing code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`navigator.getUserMedia` [is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia).

Try this instead
`navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.getUserMedia` is the legacy variant of [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)
It uses callbacks and does **not** return a promise.

You're mixing styles, either use callbacks or navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia without callbacks.